# Google Cloud Run not loading JS/Part of Bootstrap/Part of Flask engine/Part of static files

Tags: flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I've deployed my web app on google cloud today but when I open the link to my website only the HTML/almost no JS/flask functions, only some elements of bootstrap work (mostly the responsiveness that cols/rows provide, not e.g. the navbar collapse etc.) and most of the pictures I've stored in my static files aren't getting displayed as well. I suppose my Javascript doesn't work because most HTML/CSS properties provided by me / bootstrap are still working. When I run the container without cloud run everything works as it should. I run the container with gunicorn as my WSGI Server.

[This is my file tree of the webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTl7a.png)

I created the image with docker:

-docker build -t styleit .

Then I used this https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling to push my container to container registry:

-docker tag styleit eu.gcr.io/styleit/styleit (my project-id is styleit as well)
-docker push eu.gcr.io/styleit/styleit

Then I used these [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCPcC.png) [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUlgh.png) configurations for the cloud run setup.

Please don't be easy on me if I did something wrong, I want to learn how the cloud infrastructure works ^^

Comment: How do you deploy your Cloud Run service? Is it a public or private service? Can you add the command line for the deployment (or the options checked or not if deployed through the console)?

Comment: I did, hope this is enough information

Comment: Thank you for the detail, my first though was a deployment in private mode (don't allow unauthenticated). But not. Do you use a custom domain? Do you have errors in your browser? If so, what are they?

Comment: my god I'm stupid, I just checked the cloud logs not the javascript console, turns out I mixed http and https, what an easy fix. Thanks so much!